# How does a soft-start autotransformer compare to a regular autotransformer?

Tags: electrical

I'm using some commercial kitchen appliances from the U.S. in Europe, so I need to transform the voltage from 230v to 115v. I have been learning about different autotransformers, and came across some that have 'soft-start' and those that don't.

As I understand it, soft-start ramps up the voltage as it is needed by the device instead of just giving the full voltage at once. Is that true?

What devices prefer an adjusted voltage to begin with? From what I've seen, soft-start autotransformers appear to be more expensive, so I'm guessing they are probably better all around, but I don't know. Perhaps the device wants the full power straight away. How would I decide whether to get a soft-start or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally "soft-start" style circuits are used for motors connected to equipment to limit the startup torque and reduce damage to equipment.

Other equipment can use this concept if large inrush currents would be damaging to the circuits or equipment.

Resistive heating elements like those used in cooking equipment would not need a soft start. Appliances should already have a proper filter circuit for their electronic controls to limit the effect of small voltage fluctuations or spikes.

I can't really see the advantage to a soft-start for a transformer for appliances. If a product can handle being plugged in to 120 volts here in the US then they should certainly be able to handle it in Europe.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I just wondered if perhaps [link]( http://waringcommercialproducts.com/catalog.php?pcID=84_97&products_id=343) with a motor that runs at 45,000 rpm might not be a typical kitchen appliance. I have only used it with a soft-start transformer previously, and when you turn it to high-speed it gradually gets up to full power. But I don't know if this was because of how the machine is designed or if that was the affect of the transformer. Obviously no matter can go from off to full speed instantly. Just not sure what is doing what :)

Comment: *matter = motor

Comment: Wow! That is one high speed blender. You would have to contact Waring as to how their product starts up. Our Vitamix goes from 0 to full speed in a fraction of a second. That is how electric motors work. Almost instant torque. That is why large motors with belts or gears can destroy things if you don't accelerate them slowly. Hence the main reason for a soft-start or a speed drive.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Yeah it is fast! Haha. I wanted something that would really smash through anything from Nettle roots to oak chips. I think your Vitamix sounds similar, when I say 'gradually' speeding up I meant in under a second as well. I think I'll just go with a regular autotransformer though as the price difference is a lot and availability is low. Many thanks